# How to add expire date and verify token in AsymmetricCipherKeyPair( jose-jwt and BouncyCastle) C#?

Tags: c#, jwt, token, bouncycastle, jose

we use the https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt library to generate tokens which we can then transmit to other microservices to identify and authorize the information. We also use it to get all the functionality
https://www.bouncycastle.org/.

My question is how to add an expiration date to the token and how to validate it when decoding it in the code!

Comment: What did you try? You just have to add the `exp` (expiration time) to the token as shown on https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt#usage. And for verification see https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt#aspnet-core-mvc-jwt-authentication (ValidateLifetime = true). And how is your question related to BouncyCastle?